# What are the security rights for SAS token to take backup to URL?

Tags: azure, database-backups

I'm trying to take backup to Azure by using SAS token. When I put 'w' right to sp parameter in SAS token, backup fails. If I put 'rw' it works. But that doesn't make any sense. To me, only 'w' right should be enough, isn't it?

I create credential with the SAS token, then use BACKUP X TO URL =  WITH INIT, FORMAT

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you doing the backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SAS token to take backup to URL, like the sample code below.

[image]

It is obviously that the name of the container should be read.

Per my test, I use the SAS token without read permission to connect to my storage account in the Azure Storage Explorer, we are unable to retrieve child resources in the Blob Container option.

[image]

So it is necessary for the SAS token to have read and write permissions to do it.